# SQL Primary Key

Tags: sql, primary-key, unique-key

I came across the 2 versions of sql code..

```
--1
CREATE TABLE Location ( 
Id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                   NOT NULL,
Name   TEXT    NOT NULL 
);

--2
CREATE TABLE Location ( 
    Id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
                       NOT NULL
                       UNIQUE,
    Name   TEXT    NOT NULL 
);
```

In SQL, is it necessary to specify the primary key to be unique and not null?
I always assumed that the primary key was unique and could not be null.

Comment: **Don't hesitate to try executing the code.**

Comment: The 2nd one is not valid syntax. `Both a PRIMARY KEY and UNIQUE constraint have been defined for column 'Id', table 'Location'. Only one is allowed.`

Comment: @Martin. The 2nd sql statement runs fine in sqlite

Comment: @Maurice - Ah sorry I must have incorrectly assumed that this was tagged `sql-server` (which gives the error above)

Comment: @Maurice: Why are you asking a question about TSQL and checking the corresponding code in SQLite?

Comment: @Andriy. I corrected my question. I'm working on a project that uses sqlite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table can have at most one primary key, but more than one unique key. A primary key is a combination of columns which uniquely specify a row. It is a special case of unique keys. One difference is that primary keys have an implicit NOT NULL constraint while unique keys do not.

Answer (score 3):

Specifying "UNIQUE" on a primary key column is redundant - being the primary key already ensures that will be the case.

Comment: Same is true for NOT NULL, primary keys can never be nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Both UNIQUE and NOT NULL are unnecessary, because PRIMARY KEY implies both.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid syntax. It will create both a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `UNIQUE` constraint covering the same column.

There are legitimate reasons for a table having more than one key but not on the same set of columns. A table may only have one key flagged as "primary". Every table requires at least one key but there is no requirement to flag a key as "primary", even when a table has only one key.

In SQL Server, flagging as "primary" has implications (e.g. `NOT NULL`, the default key when creating a foreign key reference, etc) but I prefer to be explicit about such things. Presumably the intention is for your table to have a sole key so I suggest you omit the `PRIMARY KEY`. I further recommend you give your `UNIQUE` key an explicit name e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Location 
( 
 Id INTEGER NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT Location__key UNIQUE, 
 Name TEXT NOT NULL 
);
```